# spring-mvc : how to pass parameters in mvc without method arguments at the controller

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I was being tasked to create my controllers **without** **passing any parameters** at the method signature. 
I am quite baffled as this is quite challenge and I haven't really seen any examples at the net. 
For example: from my jsp page.

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="/project/searchResults" id="productSearchResultsForm">
        <input name="productRecord" id="productRecord" />
        <input name="resultEntity" id="resultEntity" type="hidden" />
        <input name="resultCode" id="resultCode" type="hidden" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </form:form>
```

I wanted to pass these three inputs to my controller without using @RequestParameter and @ModelAttribute at the method signature. As of now this is the only way I know how to do this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView init(@ModelAttribute ("showroomCode") String showroomCode, HttpServletRequest request) {


    logger.info("<<<< initial page <<<<<<");
    logger.info("Showroom Code : " + showroomCode);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("productSearch", "command",
            String.class);


     ShowroomUser user = new ShowroomUser();
     user.setUserId(1);
     session.setAttribute("usersession", user);
     session.setAttribute("showroomCode", showroomCode);

     logger.info(">>>>> initial page >>>>> ");
     return model;
}
```

I know that in Struts 2, you can just declare global variables in the Action class so you can automatically use them in the method without literally putting them in the method signature. Is there are way to remove this?

Thanks.

**Update**

I am asked not to use HttpServlet Request and Model Attributes at all anywhere in the code. :(
Please help!

Comment: The same instance of your Controller is used for all requests, having a global variable solution would not work correctly with concurrent requests...

Comment: Thanks Adam, would you know any way to do this in spring-mvc?

Comment: You could just add HttpServletRequest request to your method then use a series of request.getParameter() calls if you're worried about your method having too many parameters...

Comment: Thanks, do you think it is possible to do this without any usage of Modal Attributes and HttpSevlet Requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a form POJO with your attribute productRecord, resultEntity, resultCode. Ex MyForm.java

2) Set this form in the model (in your init method) Ex : `model.addAttribute("myForm", new MyForm())`

3) In your jsp form declaration set :
`<form:form commandName="myForm" >`

4) In your controller (to retrieve result)
`@RequestMapping(value = "/productSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postForm(MyForm myForm, HttpServletRequest request) {...}`

Then you can access values using `myForm.getProductRecord()` for example.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it is possible to do this without any usage of Modal Attributes and HttpSevlet Requests?

Comment: For the GET method, you must set information in the model in order to use it in the jsp. For the POST method you need at least one argument to retrieve form values. The HttpServletRequest param is not mandatory but you must use Model then. If you can't use HttpServletRequest or Model then what can you use to send/retrieve data?

Comment: That's what I don't know and what I am researching because this is what my boss deemed to be the most optimized way to speed up the performance.. :(

Comment: Ok... then ask your boss how to exchange data w/o that ;) Honestly nothing come to my mind, for me it's mandatory to use HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse when you develop a service in a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd ever want to do this.. 
But, Spring exposes the request as a ThreadLocal.  You can access it on the current thread but you can't on any spawned threads without passing it.

Here's what you do:

```
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public ModelAndView controllerMethod() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

// Do as you want with the request without having to pass it in
}
```